high cpu spikes on postgresql (rds)
I have a PG 15(.5) RDS instance, which is experiencing intermittent random(?) periods of high cpu; that do not seem to, afaict, correlate with an obvious cause:

Here is one example. The queries being made before/during & after are the same; and if run with the same params once the cpu drops back down, are quick as before. I also don't see any increase in transactions:

or tuples:

during that period; or any large vacuum. The only graph that seems to line up, is this one:

according to the pg docs, this is:

Number of times disk blocks were found already in the buffer cache, so that a read was not necessary

so I'm not clear why that would be related.
The instance is an db.r7g.8xlarge, with 1758 GiB of gp2; and isn't running particularly hot, as the graph shows. Is there something I can do to find out what the cpu is actually doing? Do I need to catch it in the act?

I wouldn't call 5% "high CPU load". I would say that everything is calm and working as it should here.

we had to move to a larger instance, because these cpu spikes were causing slow enough queries to affect users

The graphs indicate a significant increase in inserts and updates between 5 PM and 8 PM, along with a rise in concurrent sessions compared to the single-session transactions observed from 2 PM to 5 PM. While you haven't provided the overall CPU graph in your query, focusing solely on wait events could have various explanations. Since you're not seeing much WAL write activity, opening a support ticket with AWS can be beneficial. This will allow us to determine if I/O contention is the culprit. You can also check the I/O Disk Write metrics for further analysis.

the inserts & updates continued to rise, after the cpu dropped back down, so I don't see how that can be the problem. I'll try opening a support ticket, thanks
